# How to properly run a function after getting a response with angular 6

Tags: angular, gsap

In my Angular 6 app, when my component start, it first gets a feed from flickr.

When that is done, in the `finalize( )` part, iI then make it run an animation function,  `runAnim()`, but the animation doesn't fire off. It echoes out that the function is running with console.log, but nothing happens.  Using greensock tweenmax for animation.

I can make a timeout function, which will make it work but I think there should be another way to do it.

When I click the button which calls the same function, then the animation runs, so I know it works.

This used to work in Angular 2, am I missing something?

Here is a video for demonstration: http://nesthus.no/runanim.mp4

Source code can be found on [github](https://github.com/ekstremedia/angular6/blob/master/src/app/photo/feed/feed.component.ts) or below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'gsap';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
  flickrFeed: any;
  instance: any;
  updateMasonryLayout: boolean;
  tl: any;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0  });
    this.getFeed();
  }

  getFeed() {
    this.data.getFlickrFeed().pipe(finalize( () => {
      this.runAnim();
    })).subscribe(data => {
      this.flickrFeed = data['items'];
    },
    error => console.log('Error: ', error)
  );

  }

  runAnim() {
    console.log('Running animation');
    TweenMax.to('.animg', .5, { y: 225, css: { autoAlpha: 1 }, ease: Power1.easeOut });
  }

  idof(link) {
    const res = link.substr(-12, 11);
    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a `setTimeout( runAnim, 0 )`? Sometimes when your UI doesn't respond to code that you otherwise determine should be executing, it's because the code is executing on the wrong thread and doesn't have permission to update the UI at appropriate intervals.

Comment: Does it work if you put the animation firing after the subscribe code block, right after the this.flickerFeed... line ?

Comment: It seems like you're targeting HTML elements via the '.animg' class, can you include your HTML for us to see?

Comment: Jim no, Ive tried that too.

Comment: so if you manually trigger the runAnim() the animation not working?

Comment: If i add this.runAnim() when i have retrieved data, it wont fire animation. As Ian MacDonald is saying here, if i instead run this: setTimeout( this.runAnim, 0 ); , that works, im just afraid of basing it on that.